# Не работает margin 0 auto

Tags: html, css

Коллеги, добрый день, первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, прошерстил всю первую страницу гугла, но решения так и не нашёл. Не работает `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1240px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
    background-color: black;
}

.logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
        </div>
    </header>

    <main class="main"></main>

    <footer class="footer"></footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Вот, моя правка, что-нибудь понятно в форматировании кода?

Comment: Кстати, когда задаёте вопрос, есть там справка по форматированию кода в какой-то из жёлтых секций

Comment: Проблема, возможно, из-за того, что `img` - inline-элемент (инлайн-элемент). Короче, завтра опишу подробнее.

Comment: И вправду, прописал display: block - всё заработало. А почему именно это лого inline, а с другими картинками у меня таких проблем не было?

Comment: И правку глянул Вашу, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

добавьте display: inline, должно исправить проблему

```
.container {
    max-width: 1240px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline
}
```